# Target sum dp algorithm when element can be zero

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Target sum prompt:

```
You are given a set of positive numbers and a target sum ‘S’. Each number should be assigned either a ‘+’ or ‘-’ sign. We need to find the total ways to assign symbols to make the sum of the numbers equal to the target ‘S’.

Input: {1, 1, 2, 3}, S=1
Output: 3
Explanation: The given set has '3' ways to make a sum of '1': {+1-1-2+3} & {-1+1-2+3} & {+1+1+2-3}
```

let’s say ‘Sum(s1)’ denotes the total sum of set ‘s1’, and ‘Sum(s2)’ denotes the total sum of set ‘s2’. Add `negative sign` to set 's2'

This equation can be reduced to the subset sum problem `target + sum(nums)/2`

```
                  sum(s1) - sum(s2) = target
                  sum(s1) + sum(s2) = sum(nums)
                       2 * sum(s1) = target + sum(nums)
                           sum(s1) = target + sum(nums) / 2
```

```py
def findTargetSumWays(nums, S):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type S: int
    :rtype: int
    """

    if (sum(nums) + S) % 2 == 1 or sum(nums) < S:
        return 0

    ssum = (sum(nums) + S) // 2

    dp = [[0 for _ in range(ssum + 1)] for _ in range(len(nums))]

    # col == 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        # [] or [0]
        if i == 0 and nums[i] == 0:
            dp[i][0] = 2
        # [] or [0] from previous
        elif nums[i] == 0:
            dp[i][0] = 2 * dp[i-1][0]
        else:  # empty set only
            dp[i][0] = 1

    # take 1st element nums[0] in s == nums[0]
    for s in range(1, ssum + 1):
        if nums[0] == s:
            dp[0][s] = 1

    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
        for s in range(1, ssum + 1):
            if nums[i] != 0:
                # skip element at i
                dp[i][s] = dp[i - 1][s]

                # include element at i
                if s >= nums[i]:
                    dp[i][s] += dp[i - 1][s - nums[i]]
            else: # nums[i] = 0

                dp[i][s] = dp[i-1][s] * 2

    return dp[len(nums) - 1][ssum]
```

I've spent a few hours on this prompt but still couldn't pass the following example

```
[7,0,3,9,9,9,1,7,2,3]
6

expected: 50
output: 43 (using my algorithm)
```

I've also looked through other people's answers [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/discuss/97335/Short-Java-DP-Solution-with-Explanation), they all makes sense but I just want to know where could I have possibly missed in my algorithm here?

Comment: Could you please add a line explaining the idea behind your algorithm? Keep in mind SubSet Sum is a problem in NP so the time complexity will be high.

Comment: updated! The issue is not time complexity here.. I suspect my logic isn't quite right since this example set is quite small.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
from itertools import product

def findTargetSumWays(nums, S):
        a = [1,-1]
        result=[np.multiply(nums,i) for i in list(product(a, repeat=len(nums))) if sum(np.multiply(nums,i))==S]
        return(len(result))

findTargetSumWays(inputs,6)
50
```

Basically I get all possible combinations of -1,1 in tuples with the size the same as input elements and then I'm multiplying these tuples with input.

Comment: thanks but I still want to understand what I missed in my original approach

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue when handling zeroes but I did this on C++ where I handled zeroes seperately.

Make sure that in the knapsack approach skip zeroes i.e.

```
    if(a[i-1] == 0)
            dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
```

We can handle zeroes seperately by simply counting the zero occurences and we can put them in either S1 or S2. So, for each zero it is 2*(answer) and for n zeroes its 2^n * (answer) i.e.

```
    answer = pow(2, num_zero) * answer;
```

Also, don't forget to simply return zero if sum(nums) + target is odd as S1 can't be fractional or target is greater than sum(nums) i.e.

```
    if(sum < target || (sum+target)%2 == 1)
    return 0;
```

The overall code looks like this:

```
    int subsetSum(int a[], int n, int sum) {

    int dp[n+1][sum+1];
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i<sum+1; i++)
        dp[0][i] = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<n+1; i++)
        dp[i][0] = 1;
    
    for(int i = 1; i<n+1; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j<sum+1; j++) {
            
            if(a[i-1] == 0)
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
                            
            else if(a[i-1]<=j)
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j-a[i-1]] + dp[i-1][j];
                            
            else
                dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j];
        }
    }
    
    return dp[n][sum]; }


int findTargetSumWays(int a[], int target) {
    
    int sum = 0;
    int num_zero = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++) {
        sum += a[i];
        if(a[i] == 0)
            num_zero++;
    }
    
    if(sum < target || (sum+target)%2 == 1)
        return 0;
    
    int ans = subsetSum(a, a.size(), (sum + target)/2);
    return pow(2, num_zero) * ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem is this part, initializing col == 0:

```py
    # col == 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        # [] or [0]
        if i == 0 and nums[i] == 0:
            dp[i][0] = 2
        # [] or [0] from previous
        elif nums[i] == 0:
            dp[i][0] = 2 * dp[i-1][0]
        else:  # empty set only
            dp[i][0] = 1
```

This code treats zeros differently depending on how the list is ordered (it resets the value to 1 if it hits a nonzero value). It should instead look like this:

```py
    # col == 0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        # [] or [0]
        if i == 0 and nums[i] == 0:
            dp[i][0] = 2
        elif i == 0:
            dp[i][0] = 1
        # [] or [0] from previous
        elif nums[i] == 0:
            dp[i][0] = 2 * dp[i-1][0]
        else:  # empty set only
            dp[i][0] = dp[i - 1][0]
```

This way, the first value is set to either 2 or 1 depending on whether or not it's zero, and nonzero values later in the list don't reset the value to 1. This outputs 50 in your sample case.

You can also remove room for error by giving simpler initial conditions:

```py
def findTargetSumWays(nums, S):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type S: int
    :rtype: int
    """

    if (sum(nums) + S) % 2 == 1 or sum(nums) < S:
        return 0

    ssum = (sum(nums) + S) // 2

    dp = [[0 for _ in range(ssum + 1)] for _ in range(len(nums) + 1)]

    # col == 0
    dp[0][0] = 1

    for i in range(len(nums)):
        for s in range(ssum + 1):
            dp[i + 1][s] = dp[i][s]
            if s >= nums[i]:
                dp[i + 1][s] += dp[i][s - nums[i]]

    return dp[len(nums)][ssum]
```

This adds an additional row to represent the state before you add any numbers (just a 1 in the top left corner), and it runs your algorithm on the rest of the rows. You don't need to initialize anything else or treat zeros differently, and this way it should be easier to reason about the code.

Answer (score -1):

The issue with your function is related to the way you manage zero values in the list. Perhaps a simpler way for you to handle the zero values would be to exclude them from the process and then multiply your resulting count by 2**Z where Z is the number of zero values.

While trying to find the problem, I did a bit of simplification on your code and ended up with this: (which gives the right answer, even with zeroes in the list).

```
ssum  = (sum(nums) + S) // 2 
dp    = [1]+[0]*ssum         # number of sets that produce each sum from 0 to ssum
for num in nums:        
    for s in reversed(range(num,ssum + 1)):
        dp[s] += dp[s-num]
return dp[ssum]
```

What I did was:

- Eliminate a dimension in `dp` because you don't need to keep all the previous set counts.  Only the current and next one. Actually it can work using only the current set counts if you process the sum values backwards from `ssum` down to zero (which i did).
- The condition `s >= nums[i]`was eliminated by starting the `s` range from the current `num` value so that the index `s - num` can never be negative.
- With that done, there was no need for an index on `nums`, I could simply go through the values directly.
- Then I got rid of all the special conditions on zero values by initializing `dp` with 1 for the zero sum (i.e. initially an empty set is the one solution to obtain a sum of zero, then increments proceed from there).
- Starting with the empty set baseline allows the progressive accumulation of set counts to produce the right result for all values without requiring any special treatment of zeroes. When `num` is zero it will naturally double all the current set counts because `dp[s] += dp[s-0]` is the same as `dp[s] = 2 * dp[s]`. If the list starts out with a zero then the set count for a sum of zero (`dp[0]`) will be doubled and all subsequent `num` values will have a larger starting count (because they start out from the `dp[0]` value initialized with 1 for the empty set).
- With that last change, the function started to give the right result.

*My assertion is that, because your solution was not starting from the "empty set" baseline, the zero handling logic was interfering with the natural progression of set counts. I didn't try to fine tune the zero conditions because they weren't needed and it seemed pointless to get them to arrive at the same states that a mere initialization "one step earlier" would produce*

From there, the logic can be further optimized by avoiding assignments do `dp[s]` outside the range of minimum and maximum possible sums (which "slides" forward as we progress through the `nums` list):

```
ssum   = (sum(nums) + S) // 2 
dp     = [1]+[0]*ssum
maxSum = 0
minSum = S - ssum   # equivalent to: ssum - sum(nums)
for num in nums:
    maxSum += num
    minSum += num
    for s in reversed(range(max(num,minSum),min(ssum,maxSum)+1)):
        dp[s] += dp[s-num]
return dp[ssum]
```